# AE Expression: Define FontSize

Tags: after-effects, animation, after-effects-expressions

I'm making a complicated watch UI with a lot of expressions linked to different values of the display.

As you can see from the image below, **9hrs** isn't bonded to an expression yet, but it's graphically correct: **9** and **hrs** have different font sizes.

**100min** instead is bonded to an expression and it does disrupt the font formatting making **min** the same size as **100**.

[image: screenshot]

```
//This is the expression
Math.round(thisComp.layer("Orange").content("Trim Paths 1").end.value.toFixed(0)) + "min"
```

**Is there a way to tell that string that the font size for 'min' needs to be of 40px?**

**PLEASE, EXPRESSION ANSWERS ONLY**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the parameter fontSize (note the lower case at beginning and upper case in the middle?)

https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/expressions-accessing-text-property-fontsize-from-another-layer/m-p/10727207

Comment: The problem is isolating the font size expression on a portion of a text layer! So '#' is one size and 'mins' another. 
I don't know how to integrate it into that expression I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to right-align the number text layer, make a second left-aligned text layer for "min" and pick whip the position to the number text layer position?

If you wanted a different alignment you could grab the number layer width and add that to the position so it would always be offset correctly.

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know this would work but I need expression solutions only.